# How to understand this picture of E8?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:E8Petrie.svg) is the first picture you see when you go to the wikipedia page on Lie groups:

[image]

It is supposedly a diagram of the root system E8.  I understand that the 240 vertices of the diagram are supposed to represent the 240 roots.  What in the significance of the way in which the vertices are arranged?  And the different colored lines between them?

Comment: You might find the following link useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_21_polytope

Comment: Some root lattices are represented as vertices of various polytopes; the above link is a polytope in 8 dimensions whose vertices represent the root vectors of the $E8$ system.

Comment: This is a projection from dimension 8 where the roots live to a specific subspace of dimension 2 where one can see as a rotational symmetry the action of the Coxeter element in the Weyl group, which has order 30.